# Error while running Snort intrusion detection system

Tags: networking, computer-science, snort

I'm trying to run Snort on my PC ,, windows 7,I get this error every time I run it on the command prompt ,, any Ideas about this error ??

```
ERROR: c:\Snort\etc\snort.conf(511) => Unable to open address file C:\Snort\rule
s\white_list.rules, Error: No such file or directory
Fatal Error, Quitting..
Could not create the registry key.
```

thank u .

Answer (score 2):

The whitelist and blacklist files are required by the reputation preprocessor. Snort's default installation doesnt create the list files, but it is up to you to create them.

If you dont want to use the reputation processor, just comment it out or remove it from your configuration file

Comment: Or you can create empty files with name `white_list.rules` and `black_list.rules`.

Answer (score 2):

Can try disable white_list.rules and black_list.rules in snort.conf

```
#whitelist $WHITE_LIST_PATH/white_list.rules, \
#blacklist $BLACK_LIST_PATH/black_list.rules
```